# Cannot figure out why this code isn't looping a second time

Tags: python-3.x

This for loop is running once, but not running a second time.

I've put print() statements everywhere to confirm:

-round = 2, on the second pass.

-The loop comes up to the 'for' statement on the second pass, but the 'print' statement I put before "doChecks = True" didn't trigger.

-ClockCheck() is no factor; it fires perfectly first time, isn't called second time.

I've been up for ~20 hours and I figure I have to be missing something obvious.  I'm going to sleep so I can re-attack fresh in the morning...hopefully it's obvious to someone else?

```
def scoreThisRound(answerKey, round):
    global stopTime
    global gameInProgress
    userInput = []                                  #Initialize user input list

    for i in range(round):                        #This is not starting a second loop!  
        doChecks = True
        if clockCheck():                            #If there is still time remaining                              
            userInput.append(input(">"))            #Get user input and add it to a list.      

        else:
            print("ClockCheck Failed @ ScorethisRound")
            gameInProgress = False
            doChecks = False


        if doChecks == True:
            for i in range(len(answerKey)):
                if answerKey[i] == userInput[i]:
                    print("Good Answer!")                   #change this code to add time
                    stopTime += 1.5
                else:
                    print("Bad Answer!")                    #change this code to subtract time
                    stopTime -= 3
```

Here is the output from the console:

[image]

Comment: How are you calling `scoreThisRound` Also how does `clockCheck` looks like

Comment: Your screenshot shows that you actually got the second iteration, but your second input results in an exception, and you are not including the traceback that follows. Please update the question with the traceback so we can better help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, and it was something obvious.  My "if doChecks" statement was tabbed too far over; that's why it was running fine the first time (round = answers = user input), but second time the loop went (2 = 2 = 1), and threw the exception.

Lesson learned:

1) Sleep.  It's important.
2) Need to get an IDE that shows tabs and spaces as something other than whitespace, which kinda blends together for me.

Thanks!